# How do I prove this $I_x$ is an interval?

Tags: real-analysis

> Every non-empty open set of the real line is the union of a countable
>   disjoint class of open intervals.

Proof. Let $G$ be a non-empty open set of the real line. Let $x\in G$ which implies there is an open interval centred at x which completely sit inside $G$. Let $I_x=\bigcup_{x\in C\subset G \\\text{$C$ is an open interval}}C.$ We know that the arbitrary union of open subset is open. Hence, we have $I_x$ is open.

> How do I prove this $I_x$ is an interval?

In order to prove $I_x$ is an interval, we need to show any $a,b\in I_x$, the closed interval $[a,b]\subset I_x.$ Any $a,b\in I_x \implies a \in$ some open interval centered $x$ and contained in $G$($G_a$(say)), also $b\in$ some other open interval centered at $x$ and contained in $G$($G_b$(say)). How do I prove $[a,b]\subset I_x$ with the help of elementary real analysis with out using the aid of topology? Please help me.

Comment: What definition of interval are you using? I usually "define" an interval as a set of points such that if $x$ and $z$ belong to it and $x < z$ then all points $x < y < z$ also belong to it. If you use this "definition", it is quite straightforward.

Comment: yes. The same definition. But  I am able to see it geometrically. I could able to prove by connectedness. How do I prove it without these aids?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to prove is that if $x\in\mathbb R$ and if you have a family $\mathscr F$ of intervals such that $x$ belongs to each element of $\mathscr F$, then the union $U$ of all elements of $\mathscr F$ is also an interval. Take $a,b\in U$ with $a\leqslant b$ and take $y\in\mathbb R$ such that $a\leqslant y\leqslant b$; you want to prove that $y\in U$ too. There are $3$ possibilites:

- $a\leqslant b\leqslant x$: then some element $I\in\mathscr F$ is such that $a\in I$. But $I$ is an interval and $x\in I$. So, $y\in I$.
- $a\leqslant x\leqslant b$: then there are elements $I,J\in\mathscr F$ such that $a\in I$ and $b\in J$. Since $I\cup J$ is an interval (because $x$ belongs to both of them), $y\in I\cup J$.
- $x\leqslant \leqslant b$: it's like the first case.

It follows that $y\in U$.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Comment: Both the answers are very good. Not able to compare which one is best. That is why I just upvoted on both the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u,z \in I_x$. Then there exist open intervals $C,D$ such that $C,D \subset G$, $u\in C$ and $z \in D$. The union $C \cup D$ is an open interval because $x$ belongs to both $C$ and $D$. Also, $C \cup D \subset G$. If $u<y<z$ then $y \in C \cup D$ and it follows from definition that $y \in I_x$. Hence $I_x$ is an interval.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir.